# How do I get Font-Awesome to work within the confines of an eBay listing?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome, webfonts

So I've been slowly trudging my way through a responsive eBay listing template using Bootstrap, it took some trial and error but I seem to have nailed everything down except the ability to use font-awesome in the listing.

The first attempt at a solution was to point to the font-awesome cdn for the css file which is supposed to include the necessary information to embed the font, but it did not work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I read somewhere else where the link had http: in front, so I tried that, it also didn't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Then I tried to point it all directly to my own server. So I put a full path to the css file on my server:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.lqskins.com/ebay/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Then I edited the css file directly in order to put the correct path to the font files themselves in the css file, example:

```
src:url('http://www.lqskins.com/ebay/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0')
```

None of these solutions have worked. If I pull up my test template on the server that points to the same css file, they work fine there. Is there a way to load font-awesome for use within an ebay listing, or is crippled beyond workability?

Comment: I just tested linking to Font Awesome in the listing tool, and it displayed the icon. How are you loading the template?

Comment: Copy and paste directly into the listing from the original HTML template I wrote locally.

Answer (score -1):

I am having no issues with this. The following code correctly displays a cog in my ebay listing.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
```

Comment: That works on the listing page after switching from the "HTML" tab back to "Standard" but not in the "Preview listing" viewer. The icons show up as ▯